# Passing an array to a function to display a tic-tac-toe board

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to create a tic-tac-toe game for a homework project, but I am stuck in not knowing how to pass an array. Currently, I have this:

Prototype:

```
void displayBoard(char);
```

Variables:

```
const int COLS = 3;
const int ROWS = 3;
char board[ROWS][COLS] = {'*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'};
```

Function call:

```
displayBoard(board);
```

Function:

```
void displayBoard(char board)
{
    //DISPLAYBOARD displayBoard shows the current tic-tac-toe board
    //along with proper spacing

    cout << "---------------------" << endl << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << board[0][0] << "  |  " << board[0][1] << "  |  " << board[0][2] << endl;
    cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << board[1][0] << "  |  " << board[1][1] << "  |  " << board[1][2] << endl;
    cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << board[2][0] << "  |  " << board[2][1] << "  |  " << board[2][2] << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;

}
```

I have tried several variations of passing the multidimensional array to the function displayBoard but I constantly get errors such as this one:

'void displayBoard(char)' cannot convert argument 1 from 'char[3][3]' to 'char' and if I leave the parenthesis () blank I also get an error saying 'board is not initialized' which it isn't, and I don't want to use a global variable.

Comment: A `char` is a `char` and not an array or matrix of chars. You better use a `std::vector`. For example: `vector<vector<char>>`

Comment: And if you aren't allowed to use vectors, why don't you want to use a global variable?

Comment: Professor is 100% against global variables. And I will look in my book about vectors

Comment: You don't need vectors here, since there no insertion, you just need to give a matrix to your function

Answer (score 1):

Prototype should be the unintuitive:

```
void displayBoard(const char (&board)[ROWS][COLS]);
```

Using `std::array<std::array<char, 3u>, 3u>` would have more intuitive syntax.

Comment: Don't know how to use std::array<std::array<char, 3u>, 3u> but using the first unintuitive option I have undeclared variables.

Comment: @ArtByra: constant `ROWS` and `COLS` should be defined before this declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use templates for the displayBoard method if you need to display boards of differents size:

```
template <int SizeX, int SizeY>
void displayBoard(const char (&board)[SizeX][SizeY])
{
    cout << "---------------------" << endl << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << board[0][0] << "  |  " << board[0][1] << "  |  " << board[0][2] << endl;
    cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << board[1][0] << "  |  " << board[1][1] << "  |  " << board[1][2] << endl;
    cout << "_____|_____|_____" << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;
    cout << "  " << board[2][0] << "  |  " << board[2][1] << "  |  " << board[2][2] << endl;
    cout << "     |     |     " << endl;

}
```

But be careful and always check you're accessing existing indexes in your array